# Elder Thing - "This minion is not affected by opponents' cards."

Tags: smash-up

Elder Thing's rule text states that "This minion is not affected by opponents' cards."

If so, what happens if an opponent plays a card (forget it's name. It was in the Minions of Cthulhu faction) that shuffles all minions in the base to the bottom of the deck?

Is it still affected? Or is it going to stay?

Comment: I don't actually have the game - is there some reason this question is not completely trivial to answer? Elder Thing "is not affected by opponents' cards" and an opponent plays a card. So... it should not be affected, right? Otherwise, what would be the point of that rules text?

Comment: @jefromi I am coming from a Magic: The Gathering background. This card seem to be similar to Protection in MTG and there are ways to circumvent it there. But since this is a different game, I would just like to clarify if the above case is true.

Comment: The reason protection can be circumvented in Magic is that it's specifically defined in the rules as preventing a specific set of things (damage, enchant/equip, block, target), so things outside that specific set aren't prevented. But there doesn't appear to be anything like that here. The card doesn't use a term to be defined in the rules, it just flat-out says it's not affected.

Comment: @jefromi Ok. That is just what I wanted to clarify. If you want, you can post it is an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I do have the game, and this seems very straightforward to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite explicit: *"This minion is not affected by opponents cards."* That means any cards, so it doesn't get shuffled to the bottom of the deck. It will stay in play.